# Solve this ordinary differential equation in closed form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, closed-form

I saw this problem is Birkhoff and Rota's ODE.

> Express in closed form all solutions of the following  differential equation
> $$y'= \frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}.$$

I tried using substitution $y = vx$, which gives $$\int{\frac{1 + v^2}{1 - v -v^2 -v^3}}dv$$
this is not solvable in closed form(at least as far as I know and using Wolfram Alpha). Even wolfram doesn't yield a closed solution to this DE.

Comment: It is an integral of a rational function, so there must be a closed form.

Comment: @KentaS There is just not in this case. The answer wolfram conjures involves summation over roots of complex cubic idk if it is humanly even possible to reach that.

Comment: @Moo Yeah but the problem mentions closed form solutions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making $y=v x$, you effectively end with
$$\int\frac {dx} x=-\int\frac {v^2+1 } {v^3+v^2+v-1 }dv=-\int\frac {v^2+1 } {(v-a)(v^2+b v+c) }dv$$ where $a$ is the only real root of the cubic. Using partial fraction decomposition
$$\frac {v^2+1 } {(v-a)(v^2+b v+c) }=\frac{1}{a^2+a b+c}\Bigg[\frac{a^2+1}{v-a} +\frac { (a b+c-1)v+(a c-a-b) }{v^2+b v+c }\Bigg]$$ which does not make any problem.

You have
$$a=\frac{1}{3} \left(2 \sqrt{2} \sinh \left(\frac{1}{3} \sinh ^{-1}\left(\frac{17}{2 \sqrt{2}}\right)\right)-1\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The denominator of RHS suggests that one tries polar coordinates $x=r\cos(\theta), y=r\sin(\theta), r\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$. Note that then

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{\partial y / \partial r}{\partial x/\partial r} = \dfrac{\partial y / \partial \theta}{\partial x/\partial \theta}.$$

Comment: I tried, that integral is unsolvable too.

Comment: @Notwen There is a sentence in the section associated to the exercise: "Since the integrands are rational functions, this can be integrated in terms of elementary functions." (p. 18). Indeed, just as Claude's completion of your answer, one can take the pertaining integral by partial fractions. The method I suggest above leads to a rational function in trigonometric functions, whose integral is of comparable complexity. Also see: https://solitaryroad.com/c351.html .

Comment: Thank you, it was my fault that I directly put that integral in mathematica which gave a not so nice answer.